# Route to another page onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a login page in javascript. When the right user types in the right username and password it should take them to another page. I can't seem to find a way for the new page to load.

This is my html

```
 <body>
       <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validation()" method="post">
        User name:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="userid">
        <br> User password:
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="login">
    </form>
</body>
```

and this is my JS

```
function validation() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["userid"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
    if (x == "Naomi" && y == "Amaze") {
        alert("RIGHT password");
        return true;
        window.location.href = "budget/index.html";
    } else {
        alert("Wrong password");
        return false;
    };


}
```

The alerts work so I am suspecting that window.location.href isn't the correct way of doing it.

Comment: window.location

Comment: Use `window.location.assign()`. However you should note that your login validation is about as insecure as anything can possibly be.

Comment: That I am fully aware of. At the moment I am just experimenting :)

Comment: code after return statement is unreachable, it is not executed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's not working either.

Comment: @berrtech even when return true has been removed it dosn't work

Comment: Put the `return true;` after the `window.location...` or remove it as it's not needed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that has been done but it is still not working.

Comment: Then you must have another error somewhere else. Check your console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that goes after the `return` statement will not be executed. A `return` is an exit door from your function so leave it as the last instruction.

Additionnally I would add that hopefully the credential testing isn't done in the client-side JavaScript code or else it would be easy for anyone to inspect your code and find the real credentials.

Last thing : I usually tend to add a listener on the `submit` event of a form instead of ask it to return the result of a function. I can't say for sure why it is better, it just sounds more accurate to me :

```
<body>
       <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
        User name:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="userid">
        <br> User password:
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="login">
    </form>
</body>
// ...
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
        // this line prevents the normal behaviour of the form (ie: reloading the page with form data sent as POST data)
        event.preventDefault();

        // now we can check the form data
        var x = this.userid.value;
        var y = this.password.value;
        if (x == "Naomi" && y == "Amaze") {
            alert("RIGHT password");
            window.location.href = "budget/index.html";
        } else {
            alert("Wrong password");
        };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the return true; before assigning the location, the function ends, before the redirect actually happens. Move the return true to be the last piece of code, or lose it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You should return false from `onsubmit` handler it you want custom submit logic, but in your code in case if the data entered is right you return true and default submit logic kicks in, callint POST in your current location and refreshing page and not proceeding further to redirect.

https://jsfiddle.net/berrtech/L0pbeou8/

```js
validation = function() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["userid"].value;
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
  if (x == "Naomi" && y == "Amaze") {
    alert("RIGHT password");
    window.location.href = "budget/index.html";
  } else {
    alert("Wrong password");
  };
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="validation(); return false" method="POST">
  User name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="userid">
  <br>User password:
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="login">
</form>
```